# Passing values as arguments of a function defined in onchange() event

Tags: javascript, zend-form-element

I want to pass a value as an argument of a function. The function is defined on onchange() of  a text field.
I am using the following code..I use zend form to create the element.

```
$filedName = "cust_attr_".($i+1);
$fieldArr[$i]       =   $this->createElement('Text',$filedName)
-> setAttrib('class','k-textbox float_left input_width_295 k-invalid')
-> setAttrib('onchange','validateDataType('.$customerAttributes[$i]['data_type'].')')
-> setAttrib('maxlength','14')
-> setAttrib('tabindex',(++$tabStart));
```

And when i run the code i am getting the value as the argument of function..Like

`onchange="validateDataType(A)"`

But i am getting an error   **Uncaught ReferenceError: A is not defined**

How to solve this???

Comment: if you pass string parameter you will get error. valid will be onchange="validateDataType('A')" or onchange="validateDataType(12345)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A" should be passed as a string. Without the quotes it looks for A as an object.

```
-> setAttrib('onchange','validateDataType("'.$customerAttributes[$i]['data_type'].'")')
```

You will need to change `onchange="validateDataType(A)"` to single quotes... `onchange='validateDataType("A")'`